# computing total checked price in datatables with quantity (using each function jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

im new here.
I want to calculate the price of my checked row with quantity in datatables.
I already have the code. I can compute it already but my problem is,
when I checked the checkbox and uncheck it then check it again, and then I input quantity, the result is not right. but when I refresh and I check and input quantity, the result is right.
here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var crpackagetbl = $('#crpackagetbl').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    responsive: true,
    "order": [],
    "columnDefs": [
        {"targets": 'no-sort', "orderable": false},
        {className: "dt-body-left", "targets": [1]},
        {className: "dt-body-center", "targets": [0]}
    ],
    "rowHeight": '10px'
});

$("#crpackageSearch").bind('keyup search input paste cut', function () {
    crpackagetbl.search(this.value).draw();
});

var sum = 0;
var $sum = parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2);
var tots = 0;
var $tots = parseFloat(tots).toFixed(2);
var priceqty = 0;
var $priceqty = parseFloat(priceqty).toFixed(2);
var y = 0;
var $y = parseFloat(y).toFixed(2);
$('.packcheckbox').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var dis = $(this);
    console.log(id);
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var $this = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log($this);
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $qty = $tr.find('td .rowQty');
        var price = $tr.find('td:eq(3)').text();
        var $price = price.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        var $qqq = $qty.val();

        var rowCollection = crpackagetbl.$(".packcheckbox:checked", {"page": "all"});
        rowCollection.each(function (index, elem) {
            var q = $qty.val();
            $qty.keyup(function () {
                var qtyval = $qty.val();
                if (qtyval > q) {
                    $priceqty = (parseFloat($price) * parseFloat(qtyval - q)).toFixed(2);
                    console.log("qtyval: " + qtyval);
                    console.log("priceqty: " + $priceqty);
                    console.log("q: " + q);
                    $tots += parseFloat($priceqty).toFixed(2);
                    console.log("tots: " + $tots);
                    $sum = (parseFloat($sum) + parseFloat($tots)).toFixed(2);
                    console.log("add: " + $sum);
                    $('#crAllCheckedPackPrice').val($sum);
                    return false;
                    $tots = 0;
                    q = qtyval;
                    $priceqty = 0;
                } else if (qtyval < q) {
                    $priceqty = (parseFloat($price) * parseFloat(q - qtyval)).toFixed(2);
                    $tots += parseFloat($priceqty).toFixed(2);
                    $sum = (parseFloat($sum) - parseFloat($tots)).toFixed(2);
                    console.log("minus: " + $sum);
                    $('#crAllCheckedPackPrice').val($sum);
                    $tots = 0;
                    q = qtyval;
                    $priceqty = 0;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $y = (parseFloat($price) * parseFloat($qqq)).toFixed(2);
            $sum = (parseFloat($sum) + parseFloat($y)).toFixed(2);
            $('#crAllCheckedPackPrice').val($sum);
            $y = 0;
            $qqq = 0;
            return false;
        });
    } else if (dis.is(':not(:checked)')) {
        var $untr = dis.closest('tr');
        var unqty = $untr.find('td .rowQty');
        var $unqty = unqty.val();
        console.log("unqty: " + $unqty);
        var unprice = $untr.find('td:eq(3)').text();
        console.log("unprice: " + unprice);
        var unpricenumber = unprice.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        console.log("unpricenumber: " + unpricenumber);
        var unrowCollection = crpackagetbl.$(".packcheckbox:not(:checked)", {"page": "all"});
        console.log(unrowCollection);
        unrowCollection.each(function (index, elem) {

            $tots = (parseFloat(unpricenumber) * parseFloat($unqty)).toFixed(2);
            $sum = (parseFloat($sum) - parseFloat($tots)).toFixed(2);
            $('#crAllCheckedPackPrice').val($sum);
            $tots = 0;
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: is there any fiddle?

Comment: @Arka i dont know if it will work in jsfiddle. because we used <c:forEach> from struts2 so i dont know  how to make it work.

Comment: I want to compute
| checkbox | name | price | quantity |

if checkbox is checked, then the price will automatically add and show in a div. and if the user add quantity, the price will automatically multiple to quantity that has been added using keyup. it's by row. so if the checkbox of that row is checked, then that id will get